# SQL Server bulk insert error while inserting .txt file

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using SQL Server 2012 and when using bulk insert, the following error occurs:

> Msg 4832, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Bulk load: An unexpected end of file was encountered in the data file.
>   Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   The OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)" reported an error. The provider did not give any information about the error.
>   Msg 7330, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
>   Cannot fetch a row from OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)".

My query is:

```
BULK INSERT _bulk 
FROM 'D:\Twilight\Personal\Alexander\result.txt'
WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR = ',', ROWTERMINATOR = '\n')
```

The data contained in my `.txt` file is:

```
1,alex,trichy
2,arun,namakkal
3,shiva,chennai
```

Comment: I put everything from here and it works. Maybe somethink bad with your server. Or with txt file.

Comment: the answer can be found here http://stackoverflow.com/a/13129140/1692632

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your rows are terminated by `\r\n` instead of `\n`.
You can check this in text editors like Notepad++ or Sublime.

If the command below works, the line-endings were the issue:

```
BULK INSERT _bulk 
FROM 'D:\Twilight\Personal\Alexander\result.txt'
WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR = ',', ROWTERMINATOR = '\r\n')
```