# BULK INSERT fails with row terminator on last row

Tags: sql-server, csv, bulkinsert

I'm importing a CSV compiled using cygwin shell commands into MS SQL 2014 using:

```
BULK INSERT import
from 'D:\tail.csv'
WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR = ',', ROWTERMINATOR = '\r', FIRSTROW = 1)
GO
```

I have confirmed that each row contains a \r\n.  If I leave a CR/LF on the last row the bulk import fails with Msg 4832:

> Bulk load: An unexpected end of file was encountered in the data file.

If I end the file at the end of the last data row then the bulk import succeeds.

For very large CSVs a kludgy way around this problem is to find the number of rows and use the LASTROW setting for the BULK INSERT.  Is there a more graceful way to let MS SQL know that, yes, the last row is terminated and not to complain about it or fail on it?

Comment: Is the "last row" an actual row with data in it?  Or is it a blank row with a carriage-return/line-feed?

Comment: Did you try just `\n`?

Comment: File fails when last row has data ending in CR/LF, but succeeds when last row has data with no CR/LF, just EOF.  @AaronBertrand: Yes, import works with ROWTERMINATOR='\n'!  Though I don't understand why: I went through every iteration of \n and/or \r while investigating this....

Comment: @AaronBertrand: Claim your prize so I can mark an answer!  Maybe with a link to an explanation of why \r can work up to the last line but fail and \n does not fail on this scenario?

Comment: Don't feel comfortable submitting that as an answer, because I don't know why your last line would be missing `\r`. Probably the better fix would be to ensure that whatever app creates this files applies consistent line endings (usually we expect both CR + LF => `\r\n`) to every single line in the file.

Comment: @AaronBertrand: I can't figure it out either.  This is all just text editing with sed (-b), and checking the characters in Notepad++, which I assume we can trust to interpret CR as \r and LF as \n.  Every line has been processed identically and has identical terminators, which per Notepad++ are \r\n.

Answer (score 4):

Use the following :

```
BULK INSERT import
from 'D:\tail.csv'
WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR = ',', ROWTERMINATOR = '0x0a', FIRSTROW = 1)
GO
```