# OLE DB "BULK", How to spot where is happening?

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, bulkinsert

I am doing a bulk operation on sql server 2008 and I get the OLE DB "BULK" error. I know that it is because my table does not have a column that the file has or vice versa.

Despite knowing what is happening this do not help me a lot. How can I get the exact line of the bulk that is failing? Or any other hint to try to solve the error quickly.

Thank you.

Comment: check this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10507162/determine-row-that-caused-unexpected-end-of-file-error-in-bulk-insert

Comment: thanks @KeertiSystematixInfotech

Comment: are you able to get line now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Try this :](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms188365.aspx#Arguments)

```
BULK INSERT [table_name]
    FROM 'C:\...\...\[filename].csv' -- -- This is server path not local
    WITH (
    FIELDTERMINATOR = ',', 
    ROWTERMINATOR = '\n', 
    ERRORFILE = 'C:\...\...\[logfilename].log' 
    );
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Despite that now I know the row, why the log does not show the reason why it fail as the sql server management studio does in the message screen?